# MinGW: error: unrecognized command line option '-V'

Tags: c++, compilation, mingw, mod-security2

I'm trying to compile modsecurity using minGW. It may be this is in fact not possible, since it appears the directions specify to use MSVC. However, I was hoping someone could either tell me how to do it, or explain why it won't work.

My full config.log can be found at http://pastebin.com/WsprFZqK, but for the sake of posterity I've attempted to trim it to something that would fit here.

```
        This file contains any messages produced by compilers while
running configure, to aid debugging if configure makes a mistake.

It was created by modsecurity configure 2.7, which was
generated by GNU Autoconf 2.68.  Invocation command line was

  $ ./configure --enable-standalone-module --enable-java-module

## --------- ##
## Platform. ##
## --------- ##

hostname = Phoenix
uname -m = i686
uname -r = 1.0.18(0.48/3/2)
uname -s = MINGW32_NT-6.2
uname -v = 2012-11-21 22:34

/usr/bin/uname -p = unknown
/bin/uname -X     = unknown

/bin/arch              = unknown
/usr/bin/arch -k       = unknown
/usr/convex/getsysinfo = unknown
/usr/bin/hostinfo      = unknown
/bin/machine           = unknown
/usr/bin/oslevel       = unknown
/bin/universe          = unknown

PATH: .
PATH: /usr/local/bin
PATH: /mingw/bin
PATH: /bin
PATH: /c/WINDOWS/system32
PATH: /c/WINDOWS
PATH: /c/WINDOWS/System32/Wbem
PATH: /c/WINDOWS/System32/WindowsPowerShell/v1.0/
PATH: /c/Program Files/Calibre2/
PATH: /c/Program Files/android-sdk/sdk/platform-tools
PATH: /c/Program Files/android-sdk/sdk/tools
PATH: /c/Program Files/android-sdk/dex2jar-0.0.9.13
PATH: /c/Program Files/coreutils-5.3.0/bin
PATH: /c/Program Files/Microsoft SQL Server/110/Tools/Binn/
PATH: /c/Program Files/Microsoft/Web Platform Installer/
PATH: /c/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft ASP.NET/ASP.NET Web Pages/v1.0/
PATH: /c/Program Files (x86)/Windows Live/Shared
PATH: /c/Program Files (x86)/Common Files/Adobe/AGL
PATH: /c/Program Files (x86)/Intel/OpenCL SDK/2.0/bin/x86
PATH: /c/Program Files (x86)/Intel/OpenCL SDK/2.0/bin/x64
PATH: /c/Program Files (x86)/QuickTime/QTSystem/
PATH: /c/Program Files (x86)/SysInternals
PATH: /c/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft SQL Server/110/Tools/Binn/
PATH: /c/Program Files/Microsoft SQL Server/110/DTS/Binn/
PATH: /c/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft SQL Server/110/Tools/Binn/ManagementStudio/
PATH: /c/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft SQL Server/110/DTS/Binn/
PATH: /c/Program Files (x86)/GNU/GnuPG/pub
PATH: /c/Program Files/nodejs/
PATH: /c/Program Files (x86)/Windows Kits/8.1/Windows Performance Toolkit/
PATH: /c/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft SDKs/TypeScript/1.0/
PATH: /c/Program Files (x86)/Git/cmd
PATH: /c/Program Files (x86)/Git/bin
PATH: /c/Program Files/OpenVPN/bin
PATH: /c/Users/dlogan/AppData/Roaming/npm
PATH: /c/Program Files/android-sdk/sdk/platform-tools
PATH: /c/Program Files/android-sdk/sdk/tools
PATH: /c/Program Files/NetBeans 7.4/extide/ant/bin
PATH: /c/Program Files (x86)/Nmap


## ----------- ##
## Core tests. ##
## ----------- ##

configure:2650: checking for a BSD-compatible install
configure:2718: result: /bin/install -c
configure:2729: checking whether build environment is sane
configure:2779: result: yes
configure:2920: checking for a thread-safe mkdir -p
configure:2959: result: /bin/mkdir -p
configure:2972: checking for gawk
configure:2988: found /bin/gawk
configure:2999: result: gawk
configure:3010: checking whether make sets $(MAKE)
configure:3032: result: yes
configure:3145: checking build system type
configure:3159: result: i686-pc-mingw32
configure:3179: checking host system type
configure:3192: result: i686-pc-mingw32
configure:3233: checking how to print strings
configure:3260: result: printf
configure:3293: checking for style of include used by make
configure:3321: result: GNU
configure:3391: checking for gcc
configure:3407: found /mingw/bin/gcc
configure:3418: result: gcc
configure:3647: checking for C compiler version
configure:3656: gcc --version >&5
gcc.exe (GCC) 4.8.1
Copyright (C) 2013 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.

configure:3667: $? = 0
configure:3656: gcc -v >&5
Using built-in specs.
COLLECT_GCC=c:\mingw\bin\gcc.exe
COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=c:/mingw/bin/../libexec/gcc/mingw32/4.8.1/lto-wrapper.exe
Target: mingw32
Configured with: ../gcc-4.8.1/configure --prefix=/mingw --host=mingw32 --build=mingw32 --without-pic --enable-shared --enable-static --with-gnu-ld --enable-lto --enable-libssp --disable-multilib --enable-languages=c,c++,fortran,objc,obj-c++,ada --disable-sjlj-exceptions --with-dwarf2 --disable-win32-registry --enable-libstdcxx-debug --enable-version-specific-runtime-libs --with-gmp=/usr/src/pkg/gmp-5.1.2-1-mingw32-src/bld --with-mpc=/usr/src/pkg/mpc-1.0.1-1-mingw32-src/bld --with-mpfr= --with-system-zlib --with-gnu-as --enable-decimal-float=yes --enable-libgomp --enable-threads --with-libiconv-prefix=/mingw32 --with-libintl-prefix=/mingw --disable-bootstrap LDFLAGS=-s CFLAGS=-D_USE_32BIT_TIME_T
Thread model: win32
gcc version 4.8.1 (GCC) 
configure:3667: $? = 0
configure:3656: gcc -V >&5
gcc.exe: error: unrecognized command line option '-V'
gcc.exe: fatal error: no input files
compilation terminated.
configure:3667: $? = 1
configure:3656: gcc -qversion >&5
gcc.exe: error: unrecognized command line option '-qversion'
gcc.exe: fatal error: no input files
compilation terminated.
configure:3667: $? = 1
configure:3687: checking whether the C compiler works
configure:3709: gcc    conftest.c  >&5
configure:3713: $? = 0
configure:3761: result: yes
configure:3764: checking for C compiler default output file name
configure:3766: result: a.exe
configure:3772: checking for suffix of executables
configure:3779: gcc -o conftest.exe    conftest.c  >&5
configure:3783: $? = 0
configure:3805: result: .exe
configure:3827: checking whether we are cross compiling
configure:3835: gcc -o conftest.exe    conftest.c  >&5
configure:3839: $? = 0
configure:3846: ./conftest.exe
configure:3850: $? = 0
configure:3865: result: no
configure:3870: checking for suffix of object files
configure:3892: gcc -c   conftest.c >&5
configure:3896: $? = 0
configure:3917: result: o
configure:3921: checking whether we are using the GNU C compiler
configure:3940: gcc -c   conftest.c >&5
configure:3940: $? = 0
configure:3949: result: yes
configure:3958: checking whether gcc accepts -g
configure:3978: gcc -c -g  conftest.c >&5
configure:3978: $? = 0
configure:4019: result: yes
configure:4036: checking for gcc option to accept ISO C89
configure:4100: gcc  -c -g -O2  conftest.c >&5
configure:4100: $? = 0
configure:4113: result: none needed
configure:4135: checking dependency style of gcc
configure:4245: result: gcc3
configure:4260: checking for a sed that does not truncate output
configure:4324: result: /bin/sed
configure:4342: checking for grep that handles long lines and -e
configure:4400: result: /bin/grep
configure:4405: checking for egrep
configure:4467: result: /bin/grep -E
configure:4472: checking for fgrep
configure:4534: result: /bin/grep -F
configure:4569: checking for ld used by gcc
configure:4636: result: c:/mingw/mingw32/bin/ld.exe
configure:4643: checking if the linker (c:/mingw/mingw32/bin/ld.exe) is GNU ld
configure:4658: result: yes
configure:4670: checking for BSD- or MS-compatible name lister (nm)
configure:4719: result: /mingw/bin/nm
configure:4849: checking the name lister (/mingw/bin/nm) interface
configure:4856: gcc -c -g -O2  conftest.c >&5
configure:4859: /mingw/bin/nm "conftest.o"
configure:4862: output
00000000 b .bss
00000000 d .data
00000000 N .debug_abbrev
00000000 N .debug_aranges
00000000 N .debug_info
00000000 N .debug_line
00000000 r .rdata$zzz
00000000 t .text
00000000 B _some_variable
configure:4869: result: BSD nm
configure:4872: checking whether ln -s works
configure:4879: result: no, using cp -p
configure:4884: checking the maximum length of command line arguments
configure:5009: result: 8192
configure:5026: checking whether the shell understands some XSI constructs
configure:5036: result: yes
configure:5040: checking whether the shell understands "+="
configure:5046: result: yes
configure:5081: checking how to convert i686-pc-mingw32 file names to i686-pc-mingw32 format
configure:5121: result: func_convert_file_msys_to_w32
configure:5128: checking how to convert i686-pc-mingw32 file names to toolchain format
configure:5148: result: func_convert_file_msys_to_w32
configure:5155: checking for c:/mingw/mingw32/bin/ld.exe option to reload object files
configure:5162: result: -r
configure:5236: checking for objdump
configure:5252: found /mingw/bin/objdump
configure:5263: result: objdump
configure:5295: checking how to recognize dependent libraries
configure:5497: result: file_magic ^x86 archive import|^x86 DLL
configure:5582: checking for dlltool
configure:5598: found /mingw/bin/dlltool
configure:5609: result: dlltool
configure:5642: checking how to associate runtime and link libraries
configure:5669: result: func_cygming_dll_for_implib
configure:5730: checking for ar
configure:5746: found /mingw/bin/ar
configure:5757: result: ar
configure:5794: checking for archiver @FILE support
configure:5811: gcc -c -g -O2  conftest.c >&5
configure:5811: $? = 0
configure:5814: ar cru libconftest.a @conftest.lst >&5
configure:5817: $? = 0
configure:5822: ar cru libconftest.a @conftest.lst >&5
c:\mingw\bin\ar.exe: conftest.o: No such file or directory
configure:5825: $? = 1
configure:5837: result: @
configure:5895: checking for strip
configure:5911: found /mingw/bin/strip
configure:5922: result: strip
configure:5994: checking for ranlib
configure:6010: found /mingw/bin/ranlib
configure:6021: result: ranlib
configure:6123: checking command to parse /mingw/bin/nm output from gcc object
configure:6242: gcc -c -g -O2  conftest.c >&5
configure:6245: $? = 0
configure:6249: /mingw/bin/nm conftest.o \| sed -n -e 's/^.*[ ]\([ABCDGIRSTW][ABCDGIRSTW]*\)[ ][ ]*\([_A-Za-z][_A-Za-z0-9]*\)\{0,1\}$/\1 \2 \2/p' | sed '/ __gnu_lto/d' \> conftest.nm
configure:6252: $? = 0
cannot find nm_test_var in conftest.nm
configure:6242: gcc -c -g -O2  conftest.c >&5
configure:6245: $? = 0
configure:6249: /mingw/bin/nm conftest.o \| sed -n -e 's/^.*[ ]\([ABCDGIRSTW][ABCDGIRSTW]*\)[ ][ ]*_\([_A-Za-z][_A-Za-z0-9]*\)\{0,1\}$/\1 _\2 \2/p' | sed '/ __gnu_lto/d' \> conftest.nm
configure:6252: $? = 0
configure:6318: gcc -o conftest.exe -g -O2   conftest.c conftstm.o >&5
configure:6321: $? = 0
configure:6359: result: ok
configure:6396: checking for sysroot
configure:6426: result: no
configure:6669: checking for mt
configure:6699: result: no
configure:6719: checking if : is a manifest tool
configure:6725: : '-?'
configure:6733: result: no
configure:7365: checking how to run the C preprocessor
configure:7396: gcc -E  conftest.c
configure:7396: $? = 0
configure:7410: gcc -E  conftest.c
conftest.c:11:28: fatal error: ac_nonexistent.h: No such file or directory
 #include <ac_nonexistent.h>
                            ^
compilation terminated.
configure:7410: $? = 1
configure: failed program was:
| /* confdefs.h */
| #define PACKAGE_NAME "modsecurity"
| #define PACKAGE_TARNAME "modsecurity"
| #define PACKAGE_VERSION "2.7"
| #define PACKAGE_STRING "modsecurity 2.7"
| #define PACKAGE_BUGREPORT "support@modsecurity.org"
| #define PACKAGE_URL ""
| #define PACKAGE "modsecurity"
| #define VERSION "2.7"
| /* end confdefs.h.  */
| #include <ac_nonexistent.h>
configure:7435: result: gcc -E
configure:7455: gcc -E  conftest.c
configure:7455: $? = 0
configure:7469: gcc -E  conftest.c
conftest.c:11:28: fatal error: ac_nonexistent.h: No such file or directory
 #include <ac_nonexistent.h>
                            ^
compilation terminated.
configure:7469: $? = 1
configure: failed program was:
| /* confdefs.h */
| #define PACKAGE_NAME "modsecurity"
| #define PACKAGE_TARNAME "modsecurity"
| #define PACKAGE_VERSION "2.7"
| #define PACKAGE_STRING "modsecurity 2.7"
| #define PACKAGE_BUGREPORT "support@modsecurity.org"
| #define PACKAGE_URL ""
| #define PACKAGE "modsecurity"
| #define VERSION "2.7"
| /* end confdefs.h.  */
| #include <ac_nonexistent.h>
configure:7498: checking for ANSI C header files
configure:7518: gcc -c -g -O2  conftest.c >&5
configure:7518: $? = 0
configure:7591: gcc -o conftest.exe -g -O2   conftest.c  >&5
configure:7591: $? = 0
configure:7591: ./conftest.exe
configure:7591: $? = 0
configure:7602: result: yes
configure:7615: checking for sys/types.h
configure:7615: gcc -c -g -O2  conftest.c >&5
configure:7615: $? = 0
configure:7615: result: yes
configure:7615: checking for sys/stat.h
configure:7615: gcc -c -g -O2  conftest.c >&5
configure:7615: $? = 0
configure:7615: result: yes
configure:7615: checking for stdlib.h
configure:7615: gcc -c -g -O2  conftest.c >&5
configure:7615: $? = 0
configure:7615: result: yes
configure:7615: checking for string.h
configure:7615: gcc -c -g -O2  conftest.c >&5
configure:7615: $? = 0
configure:7615: result: yes
configure:7615: checking for memory.h
configure:7615: gcc -c -g -O2  conftest.c >&5
configure:7615: $? = 0
configure:7615: result: yes
configure:7615: checking for strings.h
configure:7615: gcc -c -g -O2  conftest.c >&5
configure:7615: $? = 0
configure:7615: result: yes
configure:7615: checking for inttypes.h
configure:7615: gcc -c -g -O2  conftest.c >&5
configure:7615: $? = 0
configure:7615: result: yes
configure:7615: checking for stdint.h
configure:7615: gcc -c -g -O2  conftest.c >&5
configure:7615: $? = 0
configure:7615: result: yes
configure:7615: checking for unistd.h
configure:7615: gcc -c -g -O2  conftest.c >&5
configure:7615: $? = 0
configure:7615: result: yes
configure:7629: checking for dlfcn.h
configure:7629: gcc -c -g -O2  conftest.c >&5
configure:7629: $? = 0
configure:7629: result: yes
configure:7815: checking for objdir
configure:7830: result: .libs
configure:8101: checking if gcc supports -fno-rtti -fno-exceptions
configure:8119: gcc -c -g -O2  -fno-rtti -fno-exceptions conftest.c >&5
cc1.exe: warning: command line option '-fno-rtti' is valid for C++/ObjC++ but not for C [enabled by default]
configure:8123: $? = 0
configure:8136: result: no
configure:8446: checking for gcc option to produce PIC
configure:8453: result: -DDLL_EXPORT -DPIC
configure:8461: checking if gcc PIC flag -DDLL_EXPORT -DPIC works
configure:8479: gcc -c -g -O2  -DDLL_EXPORT -DPIC -DPIC conftest.c >&5
configure:8483: $? = 0
configure:8496: result: yes
configure:8525: checking if gcc static flag -static works
configure:8553: result: yes
configure:8568: checking if gcc supports -c -o file.o
configure:8589: gcc -c -g -O2  -o out/conftest2.o conftest.c >&5
configure:8593: $? = 0
configure:8615: result: yes
configure:8623: checking if gcc supports -c -o file.o
configure:8670: result: yes
configure:8703: checking whether the gcc linker (c:/mingw/mingw32/bin/ld.exe) supports shared libraries
configure:9861: result: yes
configure:9898: checking whether -lc should be explicitly linked in
configure:9906: gcc -c -g -O2  conftest.c >&5
configure:9909: $? = 0
configure:9924: gcc -shared conftest.o  -v -o ./conftest -Wl,--enable-auto-image-base -Xlinker --out-implib -Xlinker conftest 2\>\&1 \| /bin/grep  -lc  \>/dev/null 2\>\&1
configure:9927: $? = 1
configure:9941: result: yes
configure:10106: checking dynamic linker characteristics
configure:10842: result: Win32 ld.exe
configure:10949: checking how to hardcode library paths into programs
configure:10974: result: immediate
configure:11514: checking whether stripping libraries is possible
configure:11519: result: yes
configure:11554: checking if libtool supports shared libraries
configure:11556: result: yes
configure:11559: checking whether to build shared libraries
configure:11580: result: yes
configure:11583: checking whether to build static libraries
configure:11587: result: yes
configure:11628: checking for gawk
configure:11655: result: gawk
configure:11714: checking for gcc
configure:11741: result: gcc
configure:11970: checking for C compiler version
configure:11979: gcc --version >&5
gcc.exe (GCC) 4.8.1
Copyright (C) 2013 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.

configure:11990: $? = 0
configure:11979: gcc -v >&5
Using built-in specs.
COLLECT_GCC=c:\mingw\bin\gcc.exe
COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=c:/mingw/bin/../libexec/gcc/mingw32/4.8.1/lto-wrapper.exe
Target: mingw32
Configured with: ../gcc-4.8.1/configure --prefix=/mingw --host=mingw32 --build=mingw32 --without-pic --enable-shared --enable-static --with-gnu-ld --enable-lto --enable-libssp --disable-multilib --enable-languages=c,c++,fortran,objc,obj-c++,ada --disable-sjlj-exceptions --with-dwarf2 --disable-win32-registry --enable-libstdcxx-debug --enable-version-specific-runtime-libs --with-gmp=/usr/src/pkg/gmp-5.1.2-1-mingw32-src/bld --with-mpc=/usr/src/pkg/mpc-1.0.1-1-mingw32-src/bld --with-mpfr= --with-system-zlib --with-gnu-as --enable-decimal-float=yes --enable-libgomp --enable-threads --with-libiconv-prefix=/mingw32 --with-libintl-prefix=/mingw --disable-bootstrap LDFLAGS=-s CFLAGS=-D_USE_32BIT_TIME_T
Thread model: win32
gcc version 4.8.1 (GCC) 
configure:11990: $? = 0
configure:11979: gcc -V >&5
gcc.exe: error: unrecognized command line option '-V'
gcc.exe: fatal error: no input files
compilation terminated.
configure:11990: $? = 1
configure:11979: gcc -qversion >&5
gcc.exe: error: unrecognized command line option '-qversion'
gcc.exe: fatal error: no input files
compilation terminated.
configure:11990: $? = 1
configure:11994: checking whether we are using the GNU C compiler
configure:12022: result: yes
configure:12031: checking whether gcc accepts -g
configure:12092: result: yes
configure:12109: checking for gcc option to accept ISO C89
configure:12186: result: none needed
configure:12208: checking dependency style of gcc
configure:12318: result: gcc3
configure:12338: checking how to run the C preprocessor
configure:12408: result: gcc -E
configure:12428: gcc -E  conftest.c
configure:12428: $? = 0
configure:12442: gcc -E  conftest.c
conftest.c:23:28: fatal error: ac_nonexistent.h: No such file or directory
 #include <ac_nonexistent.h>
                            ^
compilation terminated.
configure:12442: $? = 1
configure: failed program was:
| /* confdefs.h */
| #define PACKAGE_NAME "modsecurity"
| #define PACKAGE_TARNAME "modsecurity"
| #define PACKAGE_VERSION "2.7"
| #define PACKAGE_STRING "modsecurity 2.7"
| #define PACKAGE_BUGREPORT "support@modsecurity.org"
| #define PACKAGE_URL ""
| #define PACKAGE "modsecurity"
| #define VERSION "2.7"
| #define STDC_HEADERS 1
| #define HAVE_SYS_TYPES_H 1
| #define HAVE_SYS_STAT_H 1
| #define HAVE_STDLIB_H 1
| #define HAVE_STRING_H 1
| #define HAVE_MEMORY_H 1
| #define HAVE_STRINGS_H 1
| #define HAVE_INTTYPES_H 1
| #define HAVE_STDINT_H 1
| #define HAVE_UNISTD_H 1
| #define HAVE_DLFCN_H 1
| #define LT_OBJDIR ".libs/"
| /* end confdefs.h.  */
| #include <ac_nonexistent.h>
configure:12471: checking whether ln -s works
configure:12478: result: no, using cp -p
configure:12482: checking whether make sets $(MAKE)
configure:12504: result: yes
configure:12513: checking for grep that handles long lines and -e
configure:12571: result: /bin/grep
configure:12634: checking for g++
configure:12650: found /mingw/bin/g++
configure:12661: result: g++
configure:12688: checking for C++ compiler version
configure:12697: g++ --version >&5
g++.exe (GCC) 4.8.1
Copyright (C) 2013 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
...
```

Answer (score 0):

You have defined the option `--enable-java-module` but looks like JDK is not installed or not on `PATH`.

> configure:16379: checking jni.h presence
>
> configure:16379: gcc -E  conftest.c
>
> conftest.c:31:17: fatal error: jni.h: No such file or directory
>
> #include

And output variables are empty

> JAVAC=''
>
> JNI_CPPFLAGS=''